# Prestashop 1.7 - which hook to use in a module to get the used edited product quantity

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I am building a simple module where I need to catch a backoffice quantity modification event (for product or variations) in real time and send the new quantity to an external API.

I am struggling in understanding which hook to use to get the actual user inserted quantity and not the "previous" product quantity.

If I use the static method StockAvailable::getQuantityAvailableByProduct inside the hookActionProductUpdate in my module, I am getting the original product quantity and not the new one, probably because the hook is called before the actual DB update.

Any clue ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with: `actionUpdateQuantity`
You can pass the next parameters:

```
array(
  'id_product' => (int) Product ID,
  'id_product_attribute' => (int) Product attribute ID,
  'quantity' => (int) New product quantity
);
```

List of hook here : https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/hooks/list-of-hooks/

Comment: Hello, I am capable of getting new quantity inside the $params['quantity'] of the actionUpdateQuantity , but ONLY for non-variation items.  If a quantity change is performed for  one of the product combinations, there's no way to get the combination quantity and there's no similar hook for variations (actionAttributeCombinationSave is not returning quantities in $params too)

Comment: Indeed, in this case it is necessary to the parent level, recover the product id that has fluctuated, and then browse all of its variations to compare stocks

Comment: Indeed, that's what I am already doing - but it seems therefore not possible to receive the "new" edited quantity of the combinations in a hook *while* saving a product (to send them for example to an external API)

Comment: Yes it's no possible